# Query is fast with direct comparison, but not with table comparison with same column index

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures, database-performance, database-indexes

I have a fairly complex query that does a direct comparision with @EventId if provided and fast since it grabs the clustered index row.  However, sometimes I have to do a group of these Event IDs, and the second line takes almost 30 seconds to run.  I figured it would work the same way with looking up the primary key.  Is there a reason why it's so much slower?

```
DECLARE @EventIds TABLE(Id INT NOT NULL);

    WHERE 
        (@EventId IS NULL OR (ev.Id = @EventId)) AND
        (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @EventIds) OR ev.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @EventIds))
```

Comment: Look in the execution plan and tell us what is the difference between the two queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real good reason to have the expression

```
NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @EventIds) OR ev.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @EventIds)
```

The first expression, even if true, doesn't preclude the evaluation of the second expression because SQL Server doesn't shortcut boolean expressions.

Second, as table variables have been known to cause bad execution plans due to incorrect statistics and row count. Please refer to this [essay on the difference between table variables and temporary tables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16385/whats-the-difference-between-a-temp-table-and-table-variable-in-sql-server/16386#16386), topics: *Cardinality*, and *No column statistics*.

It might help to add the following [query hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) at the end of the query:

```
OPTION(RECOMPILE);
```

Yes this recompiles the plan each time, but if you're getting horrible performance the small additional compile time doesn't matter that much.

This query hint is also recommended if you have optional filters as you have with `@EventId`.

It may also help to have a primary key on `Id` defined on the `@EventIds` table variable. This would allow an index seek instead of a table scan.

Comment: I meant OPTION(RECOMPILE), not WITH(RECOMPILE) (edited).

Comment: I did put that at the end, and for some reason it sped up and took it out and it's still faster.  What in the world happened?  Did it save a slow execution plan?

Comment: I have quite a bit of query parameters in this SP.  Should I use Recompile like you said?

Comment: @MikeFlynn IMO yes. I think at some point the cached execution plan was unoptimal for the parameters you passed, causing absurd execution times. This plan is cached the first time the query was compiled, with statistics based on the parameters passed. With different parameters, this execution plan can be wildly inefficient. The option RECOMPILE causes the query to be recompiled on each execution, which leads to an optimal plan for the parameters passed.

Comment: @MikeFlynn After you removed the recompile option, the plan got cached again. You then executed with parameters for which the plan was optimal.

Comment: Yep you are right.  The new query setup does take a while to execute when its first executed, but when the faster query executes its fast, and then my slow one also works fast.  I need to make sure it doesnt use the other query plan.

Comment: @MikeFlynn A second opinion here: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).

Comment: So per your suggestion I used a hint, and used OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@EventId=1)); since the query always runs faster with an EventID present and seems to be working fine.

Comment: @MikeFlynn Indeed, other query hints might prove better for your use cases. The recompile option is quite generic, optimizing for a specific parameter might be a better average for all permutations of parameters. There is no one silver bullet that solves all cases.